# Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%-10s'

Tags: java, printf

```
String[] employees = {"abcdef", "abcdefgh", "abcd", "abcdefghi", "abcde", "abcdef"}; 
proNoun = gender[i] == 'F' ? " her" : " his ";
System.out.printf("%-10s%5s%-13s%-3d%n" + employees[i] + proNoun + "pay rate is $" +pyRate[i] );
```

why won't the format for the printf not work.

I also tried:
System.out.printf("%-10s%4s%16s%-3d%n" + employees[i] + proNoun + "\tpay rate is $" +pyRate[i]);

the whole error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%-10s'
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2780)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.implFormat(PrintStream.java:1367)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1346)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1245)
at ArraysPayRate.main(ArraysPayRate.java:20)

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is a *variadic* function, you pass the arguments to be formatted after the format string. You do not concatenate the arguments with the format string.

```
System.out.printf("%-10s %5s pay rate is $%.2f%n",
        employees[i], proNoun, pyRate[i]);
```

Comment: that ended up giving me a different error al together. abcdef       her pay rate is $Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer

Comment: @ang So you passed an `int` where your format expected a `float` or `double`. So fix that.